# Excel VBA to get IP address from a domain

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a VB script for MS Excel to get the IP address from a domain. I currently use ping but it is too slow and it takes up to 19 seconds.

I created a specific function to do this:

```
Public Function RunShell(Url As String) As String
Dim ReplacedURL As String
ReplacedURL = Replace(Url, "https://", "")
ReplacedURL = Replace(ReplacedURL, "http://", "")
If InStr(ReplacedURL, "/") > 0 Then
ReplacedURL = Mid(ReplacedURL, 1, InStr(ReplacedURL, "/") - 1)
End If
Dim Command As String
Command = "cmd /c """ & "ping " & ReplacedURL & "|clip"""
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run Command, 0, True
Dim DataObj As MSForms.DataObject
Set DataObj = New MSForms.DataObject
DataObj.GetFromClipboard
Dim CommandOutput As String
CommandOutput = DataObj.GetText
Dim IPAddress As String
IPAddress = ""
If InStr(CommandOutput, "[") > 0 And InStr(CommandOutput, "]") > 0 Then
IPAddress = Mid(CommandOutput, InStr(CommandOutput, "[") + 1,             InStr(CommandOutput, "]") - 1 - (InStr(CommandOutput, "[")))
Else
Err.Raise ERR_WRONG_URL
End If
RunShell = IPAddress
End Function
```

Is there a better approach to get the IP address from a domain in less than a couple of seconds?

Comment: When posting code, please *indent* to make it readable.

Comment: There *are* better ways, see for example [Get host name from IP address](https://www.developerfusion.com/code/1628/get-host-name-from-ip-address-and-vice-versa/). Just for info: you can pass a counter to the `ping` command as parameter, use `ping -n 1` to execute the ping only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach is relatively fast, however, execution time will be very much dependent on the connectivity between you and the server you are trying to hit. I'm hitting google/microsoft in less than a second.

I've encapsulated most of this into a simple function. Just pass the hostname you are trying to hit, and it will return the ip address.

**Function**

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GetHostIPAddress(ByVal HostName As String) As String
  Dim Pinger       As Object
  Dim PingResult   As Variant

  Set Pinger = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}").ExecQuery("select * from Win32_PingStatus where address = '" & HostName & "'")

  For Each PingResult In Pinger

    If Not (IsNull(PingResult.StatusCode) Or PingResult.StatusCode <> 0) Then
        GetHostIPAddress = PingResult.ProtocolAddress
        Exit Function
    End If

  Next
End Function
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Sub ExampleCall()
    Dim t As Double
    t = Timer
    Debug.Print "pinging: " & GetHostIPAddress("www.google.com") & " took " & Timer - t & " seconds"
End Sub
```